# Sticky Div/Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-interface, sticky

I am creating a website/portfolio and I want to make the second navbar "sticky" so that is will stay fixed to the top of the page once a user has scrolled down, I have tried to use many tutorials but none of them seem to work, what is the easiest way to complete this task.

"Here is my code for the Div that I want to stick."

```
          <div id="SecondNavBar" style="background-image: url('Images/SecondNavBar/SecondNavBar.fw.png'); height: 40px; width: 1211px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery.waypoints + waypoints-sticky
http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/waypoints-sticky.min.js"></script>

<script>$('.my-sticky-element').waypoint('sticky');</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply if window scrollTop value is bigger then the offset top value of the navbar add a class fixed to the #SecondNavBar else remove the class fixed :)

```js
var navBar = $("#SecondNavBar").offset().top;

$(window).on("scroll", function() {

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= navBar) {

    $("#SecondNavBar").addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $("#SecondNavBar").removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
#SecondNavBar {
  height: 40px;
  width: 1211px;
  background: red;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>

<div id="SecondNavBar"></div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio esse neque animi dolores inventore hic quidem vero nihil tempora itaque et voluptas facilis magni incidunt dolore nisi ratione cumque quod!</p>
```